# Do you always need to call the library when running a python function in command line?

Tags: python

The following line works in command prompt to call my function

```
python -c "from foo import xyz; xyz.aFunction(n)"
```

However, I want to continue calling the function by changing the variable n and also call other functions from xyz. Do I always need to import xyz before calling the function each time, even in the same instance of CMD?

I want to minimise the effort (characters in line of code) taken to call the function. Presumably if xyz has been imported, the function can be called easily numerous times?

Comment: A little confused by what you are trying to do. If you are going to call the functions several times and change the value `n`, don't you want to just save this in a file rather than passing a long string to the command line? But if you need to do this on the cli, it's easy enough to test no: `python -c "from string import ascii_lowercase; print(ascii_lowercase[0]); print(ascii_lowercase[10])"` works fine.

Comment: You realize people typically create and save files with their code to not have to retype them everytime?

Comment: What you write there after `-c` is a very minimal Python program. In a Python program, you just need to `import` once, and then use the imported thing. The same goes for an on-the-fly program passed to `-c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run python with the -c command, you will need to include the same imports every time because after that program is complete the python interpreter is terminated and the imports are no longer in memory.

If you want to run a simple function multiple times without writing a script, go into interactive mode by simply running `python` and you'll get a prompt like this:

```
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

This is an interactive Python session, where you can import once and keep working with the same imports in memory. Additionally, interactive mode will automatically print the result of an expression or the return value of a function called without having to call the print function. Call exit() to go back to your terminal prompt.

```
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(0, 100)
63
>>> 5**7+4
78129
>>> randint(0, 100)
37
>>> randint(0, 100)
55
>>> exit()
```

Alternatively, you can run the Python IDLE Shell to get an interactive prompt.   It should have automatically been included with your install on Windows or Mac.

[image: Windows 10 Start Menu showing Python 3.11 IDLE Shell access]